# Internal microphone on Dell Precision 5680, 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dell, microphone

The microphone worked when I first installed both Ubuntu 22.04 and the latest PopOS. I've since gone back to a plain Ubuntu 22.04 installation from the Ubuntu Desktop ISO, and the mic worked on first install. I'm not sure what changed, but now it just doesn't work.

I have the appropriate Dell OEM PPA installed - that's how my video started working.
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6/ubuntu/

In both Zoom and Discord I see the Input Device described as `sof-soundwire SoundWire microphones` but it works in neither.

What can I try next?

I have the 6.5.0 kernel installed at the moment, but I'm wondering if booting back into the 6.2.0 kernel might solve this issue.

Comment: Please be specific with details; you mention both Ubuntu & Pop OS, and a release (22.04) but not which 22.04 relates. Also given you mention it working on first install - what installation media did you use? as if it's a HWE kernel stack ISO for example; a simple fix maybe switching to an older kernel stack (*ie. what your unstated installation media used*).  You're asking about which system specifically? and what install media was used?

Comment: Thanks, I've added more details.